# Javascript disable a clickable image when other image is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i have two buttons and alert functions on both buttons. i want that if user click on 1st button the function on 1st button should work but when user click the 2nd button then the function on 1st button should not not work i mean the function should not work on 1st button if user has clicked on 2nd button. below is the code but it is not working:

```
<script>
function abc(){
    alert ("its a alert box!");
}

function xyz(){
    var a=150;
    alert(a);
}

<body>
<input type="button" value="submit 1" onClick="abc();">

<input type="button" value="submit 2" onClick="xyz();">
</body>
```

Comment: Where is the check to see if the second was clicked? A simple boolean set to true/false.

Comment: First learn to write proper HTML before diving into javascript.

Comment: I don't think its ever too soon to dive into javascript. You can use JavaScript even without HTML, the DOM, or a browser. Its ubiquitous, has no hard pre-requisites, and in my opinion not a bad introduction to the craft of programming. OPs somewhat misguided use of HTML in this example has NO impact on the code working or not in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You could use jquery to unbind the click event for the first button when the second button is clicked.  But you would need to add some id attributes so that you can do so easily.

```
<body>
<script>
function abc(){

   alert ("its a alert box!");
}
function xyz(){
   $('#btn1').unbind('click');
   var a=150;

   alert(a);   
}
</script>

<input id="btn1" type="button" value="submit 1" onClick="abc();"></input>

<input id="btn2" type="button" value="submit 2" onClick="xyz();"></input>
</body>
```

You could also further refine your code to not rely on inline onclick attributes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#btn1').click(abc);
     $('#btn2').click(xyz);
})
```

Comment: Ever heard of a little something in HTML called a head?

Comment: @Joren - not sure why your criticizing sample HTML on a JavaScript question. Furthermore, there is no requirement on JS to be in the head. As a matter of fact, its best practice for it to be at the bottom of the body. In this case, omitting unnecessary tags makes the answer more readable.

Comment: @Joren: Please elaborate.

Comment: as the w3c `<script>` reference (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html) dictates: "The SCRIPT element places a script within a document. This element may appear any number of times in the HEAD or BODY of an HTML document.". So it either has to be placed in the `<head>` or the `<body>` of the document. NOT directly in the `<html>`.

Comment: @JECarterII in your "further refinement" you can simplify that code to be `$('#btn1').click(abc)...` - the anonymous function is unnecessary.

Comment: @ZachL - thanks, I thought as much but my quick check for a reference didn't confirm my memory so I went with the verbose version.  But I agree - cleaner is better - updated.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery (since it is one of the tags you gave to the post) you can work with [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).

Answer (score 0):

For starters, don't use inline click handlers. IMHO, something like this would be nicer:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    function abc(){
       alert ("its a alert box!");
    }

    function xyz(){
       var a=150;
       alert(a);   
    }

   var bt1enabled = true;
   $('body').on('click', 'input[type=button]', function(){
      if(this.id==="btn1" && bt1enabled) {
          abc();
      } else if (this.id==="btn2") {
          btn1enabled = false; // or btn1enabled = !btn1enabled if this is supposed to toggle
          xyz();
      }
   });
}):
</script>

<body>
  <input id="btn1" type="button" value="submit 1"></input>  
  <input id="btn2" type="button" value="submit 2"></input>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<div>
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Click1"/>
<input id="button2"type="button" value="Click2"/>
</div>

<script>
$('#button1').on('click', Button1Click);
$('#button2').on('click', Button2Click);

function Button1Click() {
    alert("You have clicked button 1");
}

function Button2Click() {
    alert("You have clicked button 2");
}
```

Comment: this does not answer OPs question on how to disable one button.

Comment: Also, its general convention in JS (and eleswhere) to reserve Capitalized function names for constructors.